# Stripping 'use strict' from browserified code

Tags: ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs, eslint

I'm using [browserify](http://browserify.org) and [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify) to build my React JSX files, and I'm using [gulp-eslint](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint) as a code linter.

`eslint` insists that I include the `'use strict';` directive at the top of each file, but then `browserify` ends up scattering those directives through my generated code.

I don't mind placing the `'use strict';` directive in each file, as that makes things clearer to future-me, but is there a way to tell `broswerify` to strip out those directives?

Comment: What's the problem with how the generated code looks like?

Comment: It ends up with lots of 'use strict'; directives scattered through the concatenated code.

Comment: Yes. And what is the problem with that? No one needs to look at it.

Comment: It's wasteful and annoys me.

Comment: It's not really wasteful size-wise because generally files are gzipped. If browserify just stripped them out, it would change the behavior of the code, which could break it if it relied on strict behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using babel-eslint? or possibly change your eslintrc rules to remove strict?

https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint
`npm install -g eslint babel-eslint`

.eslintrc

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0
  }
}
```